# Java: CSV file read & write

Tags: java, file, csv, java.util.scanner

I'm reading 2 csv files: `store_inventory` & `new_acquisitions`.
I want to be able to compare the `store_inventory` csv file with `new_acquisitions`. 
1) If the item names match just update the quantity in store_inventory.
2) If new_acquisitions has a new item that does not exist in `store_inventory`, then add it to the `store_inventory`.

Here is what i have done so far but its not very good. I added comments where i need to add taks **1** & **2**.
Any advice or code to do the above tasks would be great! thanks.

```
    File new_acq = new File("/src/test/new_acquisitions.csv");
    Scanner acq_scan = null;
    try {
        acq_scan = new Scanner(new_acq);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(mainpage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    String itemName;
    int quantity;
    Double cost;
    Double price;

    File store_inv = new File("/src/test/store_inventory.csv");
    Scanner invscan = null;
    try {
        invscan = new Scanner(store_inv);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(mainpage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    String itemNameInv;
    int quantityInv;
    Double costInv;
    Double priceInv;


    while (acq_scan.hasNext()) {
        String line = acq_scan.nextLine();
        if (line.charAt(0) == '#') {
            continue;
        }
        String[] split = line.split(",");

        itemName = split[0];
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
        cost = Double.parseDouble(split[2]);
        price = Double.parseDouble(split[3]);


        while(invscan.hasNext()) {
            String line2 = invscan.nextLine();
            if (line2.charAt(0) == '#') {
                continue;
            }
            String[] split2 = line2.split(",");

            itemNameInv = split2[0];
            quantityInv = Integer.parseInt(split2[1]);
            costInv = Double.parseDouble(split2[2]);
            priceInv = Double.parseDouble(split2[3]);


            if(itemName == itemNameInv) {
                //update quantity

            }
        }
        //add new entry into csv file

     }
```

Thanks again for any help. =]

Comment: You'll find you get more and better answers if you actually ask a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suggest you use one of the existing CSV parser such as [Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) or [Super CSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/) instead of reinventing the wheel. Should make your life a lot easier.

Comment: I downloaded opencsv, but i have no idea how to use the library. Could you point me in the right direction please. Im using netbeans

Comment: For examples on reading and writing with opencsv, see  http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#how-to-read

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation makes the common mistake of breaking the line on commas by using `line.split(",")`.  This does not work because the values themselves might have commas in them.  If that happens, the value must be quoted, and you need to ignore commas within the quotes.  The `split` method can not do this -- I see this mistake a lot.

Here is the source of an implementation that does it correctly:
http://agiletribe.purplehillsbooks.com/2012/11/23/the-only-class-you-need-for-csv-files/

Answer (score 2):

With help of the open source library [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial), you could develop with pretty clean code as following:

```
private void processInventory() throws IOException {
    /**
     * ---------------------------------------------
     *  Read CSV rows into list of beans you defined
     * ---------------------------------------------
     */
    // 1st, config the CSV reader with row processor attaching the bean definition
    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
    BeanListProcessor<Inventory> rowProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<Inventory>(Inventory.class);
    settings.setRowProcessor(rowProcessor);
    settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

    // 2nd, parse all rows from the CSV file into the list of beans you defined
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
    parser.parse(new FileReader("/src/test/store_inventory.csv"));
    List<Inventory> storeInvList = rowProcessor.getBeans();
    Iterator<Inventory> storeInvIterator = storeInvList.iterator();

    parser.parse(new FileReader("/src/test/new_acquisitions.csv"));
    List<Inventory> newAcqList = rowProcessor.getBeans();
    Iterator<Inventory> newAcqIterator = newAcqList.iterator();

    // 3rd, process the beans with business logic
    while (newAcqIterator.hasNext()) {

        Inventory newAcq = newAcqIterator.next();
        boolean isItemIncluded = false;
        while (storeInvIterator.hasNext()) {
            Inventory storeInv = storeInvIterator.next();

            // 1) If the item names match just update the quantity in store_inventory
            if (storeInv.getItemName().equalsIgnoreCase(newAcq.getItemName())) {
                storeInv.setQuantity(newAcq.getQuantity());
                isItemIncluded = true;
            }
        }

        // 2) If new_acquisitions has a new item that does not exist in store_inventory,
        // then add it to the store_inventory.
        if (!isItemIncluded) {
            storeInvList.add(newAcq);
        }
    }
}
```

Just follow this code sample I worked out according to your requirements. Note that the library provided simplified API and significent performance for parsing CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

The operation you are performing will require that for each item in your new acquisitions, you will need to search each item in inventory for a match.  This is not only not efficient, but the scanner that you have set up for your inventory file would need to be reset after each item.

I would suggest that you add your new acquisitions and your inventory to collections and then iterate over your new acquisitions and look up the new item in your inventory collection.  If the item exists, update the item. If it doesnt, add it to the inventory collection. For this activity, it might be good to write a simple class to contain an inventory item.  It could be used for both the new acquisitions and for the inventory. For a fast lookup, I would suggest that you use HashSet or HashMap for your inventory collection.

At the end of the process, dont forget to persist the changes to your inventory file.

Answer (score 1):

As Java doesn’t support parsing of CSV files natively, we have to rely on third party library. [Opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) is one of the best library available for this purpose. It’s open source and is shipped with Apache 2.0 licence which makes it possible for commercial use.

Here, [this link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-csv-file/) should help you and others in the situations!

Answer (score 0):

**For writing to CSV**

```
public void writeCSV() {

        // Delimiter used in CSV file
        private static final String NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR = "\n";

        // CSV file header
        private static final Object[] FILE_HEADER = { "Empoyee Name","Empoyee Code", "In Time", "Out Time", "Duration", "Is Working Day" };

        String fileName = "fileName.csv");
        List<Objects> objects = new ArrayList<Objects>();
        FileWriter fileWriter = null;
        CSVPrinter csvFilePrinter = null;

        // Create the CSVFormat object with "\n" as a record delimiter
        CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withRecordSeparator(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);

        try {
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);

            csvFilePrinter = new CSVPrinter(fileWriter, csvFileFormat);

            csvFilePrinter.printRecord(FILE_HEADER);

            // Write a new student object list to the CSV file
            for (Object object : objects) {
                List<String> record = new ArrayList<String>();

                record.add(object.getValue1().toString());
                record.add(object.getValue2().toString());
                record.add(object.getValue3().toString());

                csvFilePrinter.printRecord(record);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fileWriter.flush();
                fileWriter.close();
                csvFilePrinter.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Commons CSV api.
FYI this anwser : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42198895/6549532

[Read / Write Example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/apache/commons/csv-commons/writeread-csv-files-with-apache-commons-csv-example/)